# Django Rest Framework Serializing Custom Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize a custom field that is not on my model. The queryset code groups the model on the item1 field and generates a count column. There is no count field on my Data model.

views.py

```
class GetDataGroups(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = (
            Data.objects.values("item1")
            .annotate(count=Count("item1"))
            .order_by()
        )

        return queryset
```

serializers.py

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    count = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ["item1", "count"]
```

How do I also get the count field to show up in my rest api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try IntergerField rather than CharField:

```
count = serializers.IntegerField()
```